# Understanding terms related to 2SAT algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, satisfiability

Recently I am learning about solution of the 2-satiability problem using strongly connected components. There is a theorem related to this problem given below:

Let $F = Q_lx_1 Q_2x_2\ldots Q_nx_n C$ be a quantified Boolean formula with no free variables, where each $Q_i$ is either universal or existential, and $C$ is in conjunctive normal form. That is, $C$ is a conjunction of clauses, each clause is a disjunction of literals, and each literal is either a variable, $x_i$, or the negation of a variable, $x_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq n$).

> **Theorem 2:** The formula $F$ is true if and only if none of the following three conditions holds:
>
> 3(i) An existential vertex $u$ is in the same strong component as its complement $u’$.
>
> 3(ii) A universal vertex $u_i$ is in the same strong component as an existential vertex $u_j$ such that $j < i$ (i.e., $x_i$ is not quantified within the scope of $Q_i$).
>
> 3(iii) There is a path from a universal vertex $u$ to another universal vertex $v$. (This condition includes the case that $v = u$.)

In the proof they use this definition:
We call a vertex universal if the corresponding variable is universally quantified and existential otherwise.

But I am not familiar with the terms *universal vertex* and *existential vertex*. Can any one please explain these terms to me?

Comment: What is the source? It should define the terms it uses. To me, a *universal vertex* is a vertex adjacent to every other vertex.

Comment: The terms *universal vertex* and *existential vertex* are specific to the theorem, and should be defined as part of the proof.

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/account if you need help with your account.

Answer (score 3):

The terms *universal vertex* and *existential vertex* are not universal, but rather specific to this specific theorem. The context is a graph on the set of literals (variables and their complements). Presumably for every clause $\ell_1 \lor \ell_2$ in $C$, there is an arrow from $\bar{\ell}_1$ to $\ell_2$.

A vertex is called *universal* if its corresponding variable is universally quantified, that is, quantified as $\forall x_i$. In other words, if $Q_i x_i = \forall x_i$ then the vertices $x_i$ and $\bar{x}_i$ are universal.

Similarly, a vertex is called *existential* if its corresponding variable is existentially quantified, that is, quantified as $\exists x_i$.